# Rename column R

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, tidy

I am trying to rename columns but I do not know if that column will be present in the dataset. I have a large data set and if a certain column name is present I want to rename it. For example:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   4   5   9   2
3   5   6   9   1
4   4   4   9   1

newNames <- data %>% rename(1=A,2=B,3=C,4=D,5=E)
```

This works to rename what is in the dataset but I am looking for the flexibility to add more potential name changes, without an error occurring.

```
newNames2 <- data %>% rename(1=A,2=B,3=C,4=D,5=E,6=F,7=G)
```

This ^ will not work it give me an error because F and G are not in the data set.

Is there any way to write a code to ignore the column change if the name does not exist?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I tried to post an example of a dataset but it did not go through right but basically the letters are the column names I am trying to change

Comment: You can't rename something that doesn't exist. You could always just use the `names()` function, something like `names(data) <- 1:length(data)`. That way, you just rename all of the columns in the dataframe, wihout knowing how many there are.

Comment: I get different datasets that I am trying to format and some would hypothetically have "A","C","D" and another could have "B","C","E". I am trying to have one code that will rename whatever variables are present for that dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be plenty of ways to do this. One would be to create a named vector with the names and their corresponding 'new name' (as the vector's names) and use that, i.e.

```
#The below vector v1, uses LETTERS as old names and 1:7 as the new ones
v1 <- setNames(LETTERS[1:7], 1:7)
names(df) <- names(v1)[v1 %in% names(df)]
```